# bash timeout command kills randomly before duration

Tags: bash, timeout, process-substitution

I'm trying to show thumbnails from youtube for specific timeout to user and then show next one
I made this command:

```
while read line; do\
      wget -O- -q "$line" | \
      timeout 10s display ;\
done < <(youtube-dl --get-thumbnail https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPBdQRkWvGY https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybLXm5LOSks https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fr3ECCSo6U https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKST1uliDU8 )
```

But the images are shown for random time (some 10s and some 1s !!)

Does anyone have any idea what is them problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shell pipeline executes the programs of the pipeline not one after another, but more or less at the exact same time (less so as the system becomes increasingly busy) as is shown by when the first three following `date` calls execute:

```
$ date +%s; (date +%s >&2; sleep 3) | (date +%s >&2; sleep 5); date +%s
1502224035
1502224035
1502224035
1502224040
$
```

Therefore the `timeout` timer is already counting down while `wget` is busy downloading the data but before `display` has had a chance to display said data.

One workaround would be to download the data in advance so that there is a list of files for display to work on; this would remove the delays caused by `wget` from the `display` portion.

```
#!/bin/sh
...
get_the_files_here
for f in a_glob_that_matches_the_files_here; do
    timeout 10s display "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem is that you and `timeout` see different starting points:

For you the timeout should begin when the image is displayed. But for `timeout` it begins when it is started.

There is a "random" gap between these two points in time: the download time. You must delay the execution of `timeout` until the download is finished.